# Is it possible to use a Mac's USB ports remotely through VNC/Remote Desktop?

Tags: usb, server.app, remote-desktop, apple-configurator

A little background: my organization, a hospital, is in the process of rolling out more iOS devices throughout the enterprise and we are provisioning them through Apple Configurator (w/ Cisco Meraki MDM) which has been working well so far.

However, this is mostly a PC shop and there's only one Mac computer for the device provisioning as of right now, so the question was brought to me if there was a way that we could host a Mac server in our data center and have the USB ports "redirect" so to speak from the local machine to the Mac server in order to provision these iOS devices without having to p-card multiple Mac computers?

Comment: Are you looking for a USB over ethernet adapter to test that? It might just work. Are you looking to manage 5 iPads or 5,000? Most people use an MDM that allows supervision over networking rather than trying to work over USB.

Comment: We're rolling out MDM but as of right now there's still stuff that has to be done on the configurator end. Not exactly where I would like to be yet, but it's a start.

Comment: What do you mean "p-card multiple Mac computers?"

Comment: To purchase. (Using office lingo by mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, pretty sure you won't be able to use a Mac server and then connect iOS devices to PCs and prepare them using Configurator remotely. You can add more USB ports using a hub to increase the number you can connect simultaneously.